# Contribute CS4 - how to add custom css styles

Tags: content-management-system, adobe-contribute

Can someone explain how can I add custom font, css classes styles to Contribute?

styles for h1, h2, h3, ul, ol, p, span, blockquote, etc

The problem that I'm having is that when I go to edit the page, only header styles appear but none of the rest. How can I make all of the styles that I have on the css to appear to the WYSIWYG?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the settings on the "Publisher Settings" in Contribute.

There is a page "Styles and fonts" where you can allow the users to select all of your CSS elements.

Preferably you normally only make a selection of styles that you want the user to be able to choose. You can do this with a seperate CSS where you specify the styles that a user can select. This file doesn't contain much only some styles normally without actual formatting which is still in you main stylesheet.

See this tutorial for some help:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/contribute/articles/css_03.html

Comment: Great. I know Contribute is not the best CMS of the world, but this does it. Thanks. Really appreciated.